# LockRows plan node taking long time

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query in Postgres ([emulating a work queue](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/)):

```
DELETE FROM work_queue
WHERE id IN ( SELECT l.id
              FROM work_queue l
              WHERE l.delivered = 'f' and l.error = 'f' and l.archived = 'f'
              ORDER BY created_at
              LIMIT 5000
              FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED );
```

While running the above concurrently (4 processes per second) along with a concurrent ingest at the rate of 10K records/second into `work_queue`, the query effectively bottlenecks on `LockRow` node.

Query plan output:

```
 Delete on work_queue  (cost=478.39..39609.09 rows=5000 width=67) (actual time=38734.995..38734.998 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=478.39..39609.09 rows=5000 width=67) (actual time=36654.711..38507.393 rows=5000 loops=1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=477.96..527.96 rows=5000 width=98) (actual time=36654.690..36658.495 rows=5000 loops=1)
               Group Key: "ANY_subquery".id
               ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=0.43..465.46 rows=5000 width=98) (actual time=36600.963..36638.250 rows=5000 loops=1)
                     ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..415.46 rows=5000 width=51) (actual time=36600.958..36635.886 rows=5000 loops=1)
                           ->  LockRows  (cost=0.43..111701.83 rows=1345680 width=51) (actual time=36600.956..36635.039 rows=5000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using work_queue_created_at_idx on work_queue l  (cost=0.43..98245.03 rows=1345680 width=51) (actual time=779.706..2690.340 rows=250692 loops=1)
                                       Filter: ((NOT delivered) AND (NOT error) AND (NOT archived))
         ->  Index Scan using work_queue_pkey on work_queue  (cost=0.43..7.84 rows=1 width=43) (actual time=0.364..0.364 rows=1 loops=5000)
               Index Cond: (id = "ANY_subquery".id)
 Planning Time: 8.424 ms
 Trigger for constraint work_queue_logs_work_queue_id_fkey: time=5490.925 calls=5000
 Trigger work_queue_locked_trigger: time=2119.540 calls=1
 Execution Time: 46346.471 ms
```

(corresponding visualization: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/ZaZ)

Any ideas on improving this? Why should locking rows take so long in the presence of concurrent inserts? Note that if I do not have concurrent inserts into the `work_queue` table, the query is super fast.

Comment: Are rows ingested with back-dated created_at times?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using PG 12. Rows are ingested with `now()` as the default created_at so they are not backdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can see that the index scan returned 250692 rows in order to find 5000 to lock.  So apparently we had to skip over 49 other queries worth of locked rows.  That is not going to be very efficient, although if static it shouldn't be as slow as you see here.  But it has to acquire a transient exclusive lock on a section of memory for each attempt.  If it is fighting with many other processes for those locks, you can get a cascading collapse of performance.

If you are launching 4 such statements per second with no cap and without waiting for any previous ones to finish, then you have an unstable situation.  The more you have running at one time, the more they fight each other and slow down.  If the completion rate goes down but the launch interval does not, then you just get more processes fighting with more other processes and each getting slower.  So once you get shoved over the edge, it might never recover on its own.

The role of concurrent insertions is probably just to provide enough noisy load on the system to give the collapse a chance to take a foothold.  And of course without concurrent insertion, your deletes are doing to run out of things to delete pretty soon, at which point they will be very fast.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense. I have now asked a similar question here which uses a different query for the work queue pattern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67449257/update-performance-degrades-over-time-work-queue-pattern

This was the original query which we were using but were analysing a switch to `DELETE FROM ...` because of the issue aforementioned.