# UPDATE performance degrades over time (work queue pattern)

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have the following query in Postgres ([emulating a work queue](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/what-is-select-skip-locked-for-in-postgresql-9-5/)):

```
UPDATE work_queue
SET locked = NOW()
WHERE id IN ( SELECT l.id
              FROM work_queue l
              WHERE l.delivered = 'f' and l.error = 'f' and l.archived = 'f'
                    and (l.locked IS NULL or l.locked < (NOW() - interval '30 minute'))
              ORDER BY created_at
              LIMIT 5000
              FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED);
```

While running the above continuously (single process sequentially) along with concurrent inserts at the rate of 10K records/second into `work_queue`, the query seems to degrade quickly and bottleneck on the UPDATE node.

Query plan output:

```
 Update on work_queue  (cost=818.73..42608.77 rows=5000 width=340) (actual time=11888.176..11888.178 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=818.73..42608.77 rows=5000 width=340) (actual time=2324.232..3582.806 rows=5000 loops=1)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=818.18..868.18 rows=5000 width=98) (actual time=2324.200..2330.149 rows=5000 loops=1)
               Group Key: "ANY_subquery".id
               ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=0.43..805.68 rows=5000 width=98) (actual time=277.548..2270.610 rows=5000 loops=1)
                     ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..755.68 rows=5000 width=51) (actual time=277.542..2256.145 rows=5000 loops=1)
                           ->  LockRows  (cost=0.43..673154.10 rows=4456536 width=51) (actual time=277.539..2255.134 rows=5000 loops=1)
                                 ->  Index Scan using work_queue_created_at_idx on work_queue l  (cost=0.43..628588.74 rows=4456536 width=51) (actual time=234.769..792.327 rows=10352 loops=1)
                                       Filter: ((NOT delivered) AND (NOT error) AND (NOT archived)  AND ((locked IS NULL) OR (locked < (now() - '00:30:00'::interval))))
                                       Rows Removed by Filter: 882
         ->  Index Scan using work_queue_pkey on work_queue  (cost=0.56..8.35 rows=1 width=263) (actual time=0.249..0.249 rows=1 loops=5000)
               Index Cond: (id = "ANY_subquery".id)
 Planning Time: 2.313 ms
 Execution Time: 11888.757 ms
```

(visualization: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/Evr)

It's not clear why the UPDATE node should be so slow (isn't it trying to update primary key rows?). Any suggestions to improve the performance here? (Note: If there are no concurrent inserts into `work_queue` table then performance is more or less consistent)

**UPDATE 1**

I checked blocked queries using:

```
SELECT
    activity.pid,
    activity.usename,
    activity.query,
    blocking.pid AS blocking_id,
    blocking.query AS blocking_query
FROM pg_stat_activity AS activity
JOIN pg_stat_activity AS blocking ON blocking.pid = ANY(pg_blocking_pids(activity.pid));
```

and I saw that the above update query was blocked on one of the insert processes. The inserts themselves were blocked on other insert processes.

**UPDATE 2:**

Digging deeper into Update 1, I could capture what the inserts were waiting on (PS: `users` has a AFTER INSERT trigger which inserts into `work_queue`):

```
blocked_pid | blocked_mode  | blocked_locktype | blocking_pid | blocking_user |            blocked_statement             |  current_statement_in_blocking_process
-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+---------------+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
        6675 | ExclusiveLock | extend       |         6613 | postgres      | insert into "users" (name) select 'a' from generate_series(1,1000);  | insert into "users" (name)  select 'a' from generate_series(1,1000);

< few 100 of such entries>
```

I could only capture this occasionally. I also saw that the `UPDATE work_queue` was blocked on such an insert and also vice-versa i.e. `INSERT into users` was also sometimes blocked on the `UPDATE work_queue`.

I guess these are just internal LOCK waits and nothing that the application developer can do anything about?

Comment: In my hands this slows down in a different spot, the index scan on work_queue_created_at_idx.  Every time it executes, it needs to filter out 5000 more rows than it did last time, and so this gets slower and slower.  That slow down makes it impractical to run long enough to see if there would be another slow down.  Do you have some kind of clean up process you have not described?

Comment: You should turn on track_io_timing and get the execution plan with BUFFERS specified.

Comment: Yes, we periodically prune the table. We also changed the index to a partial index so that the index scan to find relevant rows doesn't scan old rows (`CREATE INDEX work_queue_experimental ON work_queue (created_at, locked)  WHERE delivered = 'f' 
and error = 'f' and archived = 'f'`

But still I am seeing fairly frequent UPDATE node bottlenecks (this only happens with concurrent ingests): https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/dRC

Comment: I also added an update to the original post: The UPDATE query seems to be blocking on the inserts.

Comment: @jjanes Sorry to bother, but I added 2 updates (and a comment with io_tracking) if you are still interested. It is quite perplexing to see an `ExclusiveLock` being acquired for concurrent INSERTs.

Comment: Have you tried `CREATE INDEX work_queue_locker ON work_queue ( delivered, error, archived, locked, created_at);` . That index [covers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) your subquery and may make it faster.